# how to host wcf service?

Tags: iis-7, wcf, wcf-hosting

I develop some WCF service on own computer (in office).
Now, I have to publish it on office server.

Office server is Windows Server 2008 R2 (IIS7).
What should I do, to access my service on some address? like 192.168.1.99:5555?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer this link. This will help you...

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-4-Host_a_WCF_Service_in_IIS_7_-and-amp;_Windows_2008_-_The_right_way.aspx